# How to assign textfield or any delegate in Swift Language?

Tags: swift, delegates, uitextfield

I am just new born developer for Swift Language.
I want to assign textfield delegate to view controller. I tried to assign like this

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

It's returning following error **"Cannot specialize non-generic type 'UIViewController'"**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add Protocols you want to conform using comma:

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
```

You can only extend *only* from one class, but conform with as many protocols as you want:

```
    class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate
```

From [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html):

```
class SomeClass: SomeSuperclass, FirstProtocol, AnotherProtocol {
    // class definition goes here
}
```

Comment: what if there will be multiple delegates? class LoginViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate is this proper method?

Comment: Updated answer: Yes, that's the way to do it

Comment: Great. +1 for quick help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use comma to add Delegates/ Datasource / Protocols:

```
class MyClass: UIViewController ,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource ..
{...}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that you can separate your code for more readability by conforming to your protocols in the `extension` of your class:

```
class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    [your class implementation]

}

extension DetailViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    [list of your delegate methods]

}
```

Personally I like this approach better.